# DM script to trigger "Capture" button

Tags: dm-script

Is there a function to trigger the camera acquisition button in DM?
I am looking for this for K3 camera. For K camera, the built-in "Capture" button acquires many fast cycles within the exposure time. This cannot be achieved by regular `CameraAcquire` function.
Looking for function either emulate the action of "Capture", or just trigger that button.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. There is only a script interface to camera acquisition itself, not linked to the UI.

Comment: Thanks. For DigiScan, there is one, {void DSInvokeAcquisitionButton(number mode) }. I am hoping there is one for camera.

Comment: @user6406828 Yes, both DigiScan and SpectrumImaging have UI-based script interfaces. (DigiScan also has a parameter set based one, which should possibly be preferred) But no other product has. Camera has two interfaces. One is officially supported and documented but limited in scope, the other is undocumented but also parameter-set based and also available with the C++ SDK which you can request via the Gatan homepage. While not officially supported, Gatan has in the past been quite helpful with it when directly and nicely contacted about it by customers.